# Property property of OptionalMemberExpression expected node to be of a type ["Identifier"] but instead got "CallExpression"

Tags: typescript, babeljs, optional-chaining

I have a line of code that looks something like this:

```
return someObj.getSomething(param).doSomethingElse().key.anotherKey
```

All of my jest unit tests pass.

In order to be a bit safer, I added optional chaining to that line so now it looks like:

```
return someObj?.getSomething(param)?.doSomethingElse()?.key?.anotherKey
```

As soon as I do that, the corresponding test suite results in errors:

```
Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Property property of OptionalMemberExpression expected node to be of a type ["Identifier"] but instead got "CallExpression"

      at validate (node_modules/@babel/types/lib/definitions/utils.js:132:11)
      at Object.validator [as validate] (node_modules/@babel/types/lib/definitions/core.js:1451:11)
      at validateField (node_modules/@babel/types/lib/validators/validate.js:24:9)
      at Object.validate (node_modules/@babel/types/lib/validators/validate.js:17:3)
      at NodePath._replaceWith (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/replacement.js:179:7)
      at NodePath.replaceWith (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/replacement.js:161:8)
      at RewireState.Identifier (node_modules/babel-plugin-rewire/lib/babel-plugin-rewire.js:187:10)
      at NodePath._call (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:55:20)
      at NodePath.call (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:42:17)
      at NodePath.visit (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:92:31)
```

The optional chaining plugin is added in my `package.json` file as so:

```
"dependencies" : {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": 7.14.5
}
```

and in my `babel.config.js` file as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since `babel-plugin-rewire` is in there, sounds like a bug in that?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?